# Why my program outputs weird characteres?

Tags: c, cs50

When I use 3 or more names my programs outputs weird characters.

When I use 2 is totally fine, when I use a lot of spaces is all good as well.

But when I try
   kaue  rodrigo   pacheco
The output is:
KRP]A

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
string name = get_string("What is your name?\n");

// initiate array that will contain all the initials
char initials[10];

// initials index
int index = 0;

// if first character is not a space then append to initials
if (name[0] != 32)
{
        // if the character is not between A-Z
        if (!(name[0] >= 'A' && name[0] <= 'Z'))
        {
            // transform it in uppercase
            name[0] = name[0] - 32;
        }
        // append the character into initials array
        initials[index] = name[0];
        // keep track on how many were done
        index++;
}


// iterate through the user input
for (int i = 1; i < strlen(name); i++) 
{
    if ((name[i] != 32) && (name[i - 1] == 32))
    {
        // if the character after the blankspace is not between A-Z
        if (!(name[i] >= 'A' && name[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            // transform it in uppercase
            name[i] = name[i] - 32;
        }
        // append the character into initials array
        initials[index] = name[i];
        // keep track on how many were done
        index++;
    }
}
// end result, prints all initials uppercase
printf("%s\n", initials);
```

}

Comment: null terminator

Comment: `if (!(name[0] >= 'A' && name[0] <= 'Z'))` should be `if (name[0] >= 'a' && name[0] <= 'z')` (subject to continuous alphabet coding). Consider using `islower(name[0])`.

Comment: @JeffMercado can you elaborate?

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the

`initials[index] = 0;` before the `printf`. You do not terminate your char array with zero. The C string a number of chars with the zero at the end

Comment: It worked, but I still didn`t really get it why. Could you elaborate? Thank you

Comment: you need 0 at the end of the string to be a C string.

Comment: Got it, but what is the output ]A?

Comment: it can anyting - it is just something left in the memory. UB